# Create asynchronous event with javascript promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a large array(say over 1 000 000 elements that I would like to sort asynchronously so that it doesn't block the execution of the rest of my program.
I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so I was wondering if this would work.

```
var sortFunction = function(arr){
    return new Promise(resolve, reject){
        arr.sort();
        resolve(arr);
   }
}
sortFunction(hugeArray).then(function(arr){
    //do something
})
```

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question so that I may learn more about JavaScript functions. I don't actually have an array or a program to run

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. That will still block the server from doing anything else while the sort is running. You would need to run it in a different process (or in a browser, using web-workers), for it to actually run in parallel with other JavaScript.

Comment: then theoretically it wont work mainly because your Promise constructor is wrong

Comment: The only difference between that and just a call to `arr.sort()`, is that subsequent lines (outside the `then` callback) will execute before the sort starts in that version, whereas if you just did `arr.sort();` directly, subsequent lines will execute after.

Comment: You need to look at some kind of [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) as just using promise won't solve your problem

Comment: Why do you think this is an "asynchronous **event**"?

Comment: Have a look at [Computing with JavaScript Web Workers](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/)

Comment: Ahh thanks for all the responses. Makes sense now. So say I did use Web Workers to compute my arr.sort() on a different thread, would that then no longer block the execution of my JavaScript program? Or say my arr.sort() was actually an http request, would that also not block the execution of my program?

Comment: Correct, neither of those would block the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually possible, but experimental. You need to offload the work to a separate thread. You need to use the sparsely supported but useful [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) and offload the work to a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

You have to use both the web worker and the `SharedArrayBuffer`, only using a web worker won't help you because serializing will be too expensive. [It has to be a zero-cost copy operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Passing_data_by_transferring_ownership_(transferable_objects))

Here is [an example gist](https://gist.github.com/dherman/5463054) on how to perform this.